# Django URL as a variable not working for external site

Tags: django, jinja2

I have a link being rendered to a template in Django, which changes from record to record. the HTML comes up blank, even though I verified the link works when hard coding it in the site.

HTML source rendered:

```
<div id="container2">
    <img id="image2" src="" style="width:75%;height:40%;">
</div>
```

source HTML template:

```
<div id="container2">
    <img id="image2" src="{{trip.pcs_mca_image.url}}" style="width:75%;height:40%;">
</div>
```

the variable itself is a fully qualified URL such as https://googalopolis.photos.category.jdslkjf.blah.blah

when I copy/paste the URL and not use jinja variable it works, but this is issue as each refresh is a new link.

Model:
(note other fields render on template just fine as text fields, but not the two URL strings even when put on the template without a img or href)

```
class TPEBLS(models.Model):
    trip_key = models.CharField(db_column='Trip_Key', max_length=17, blank=True, primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    run_field = models.CharField(db_column='Run#', max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters. Field renamed because it ended with '_'.
    downgraderequester = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DowngradeRequester', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    pcs_mca_obtained = models.CharField(db_column='PCS_MCA_Obtained', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pcs_mca_image = models.CharField(db_column='PCS_MCA_Image', max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

view passing the fields exert:

```
    currentTrip = resultSet.all().filter(trip_key=resultSetTripKeys[0])

    print(currentTrip.values_list('run_field', flat=True))
    print(currentTrip.values_list('facesheet_image', flat=True))
    print(resultSet)

    ctx = {"trip" :currentTrip, 
           "currentTripID": resultSetTripKeys[0],
            "QAfields": QAfields.objects.values_list('reviewItem', flat=True).filter(area='Coding'), 
            "chkclaims": QAfields.objects.values_list('reviewItem', flat=True).filter(area='Claims')

           }
    return render(request, 'QAWorkspace/trip_review_single.html', ctx)
```

Comment: Ive tried {{trip.PCS_MCA_Image}}, adding.URL, and concatenating blank text. none worked. The field from the model is a Text field URL

Comment: Can you show the model in question, as well as how you are passing this variable to the template in a view of some sort?

Comment: Modified to show exert from model and view passing the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

the attribute was outside of the

{%for trip in trip %} block

I still don't understand why you need to have a for loop on template, but I knew I was looking in all the wrong places with the URL validating/ect.